# Why is my progam asking the same questions twice when passing an argument?

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing

This code is asking for the same questions twice when I only need the argument toBePainted

```
public static int getToBePainted(){
    //Gets the rooms square footage
    int height = 0;
    String heightString = "";
    int width = 0;
    String widthString = "";
    int length = 0;
    String lengthString = "";
    int toBePainted = 0;

    heightString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" What is the hieght of the ceiling in feet: ");
    widthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the width of the room in feet: ");
    lengthString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the length of the room in feet: ");
    height = Integer.parseInt(heightString);
    width = Integer.parseInt(widthString);
    length = Integer.parseInt(lengthString);

    toBePainted = Math.round((((length * width) * 4) + (height * width)) - (6));

    return toBePainted;
}

public static int getBaseAmmount(){
    int squareFeet = getToBePainted();
    int baseAmmount = 0;
    int gallons = 0;

    gallons = (squareFeet / 400);
    if (gallons < 1) {
        gallons = 1;
    }

    baseAmmount = (gallons * 30);

    return baseAmmount;
}
```

I just need to get the answer from getToBePainted to be passed not the whole function.

Comment: Both `getBaseAmmount()` and `getToBePainted()` are parameterless - you *aren't* passing any arguments. You're *returning* a value from `getToBePainted()`, if that's what you mean. But you're only calling that method once, so it's not going to ask questions twice. Please provide a [mcve] and make your question clearer. As an aside, I'd strongly advise against the style of "declare all local variables at the start of the method" - declare them where you first *need* them. Your code will be shorter and clearer.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). Please 
[enhance](/posts/46617439/edit) you example to be
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](/help/mcve).